# Change div background with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, css, cordova

i have a div that i want to change the background-image. on my code it will change when the page is loaded if a parameter is changed. i wrote a sample code on this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/08ovv0r4/

As you can see, when i press the button, the div background is changed but on my code the background image just doesn't load, just change to a white background.
css of div on my code:

```
div[data-role="page"]{ 
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
background-image:url('../img/blue_background.jpg');
}
```

the line of code where i change the background:

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').css('background-image','url("../img/green.jpg")');
```

the new image is on img file inside my www file. there is no problem to the code to load the initial image on the css but when i change it, doesn't load. already tried many answers of some questions here on stackoverflow but none of them resolved.
Any help?

Comment: Your code appears to work for me. The background image changes to an image with a black/green gradient.

Comment: code is working for me..any specific browser or instance?

Comment: yes i know the example on the jsfiddle file is working but on my code it's not, whatever i do, just change to a white background

Comment: @TiagoPina, are you using the correct paths?

Comment: please add the html also

Comment: can you tell your project folder structure, where you keep your images and JavaScript with respect to project root folder?

Comment: @Desperado the html is the same of jsfiddle file.

Comment: @ToniAlmeida yes, because it's in the same folder that is the inicial image and the path is the same, just the name of the image is changed, that's why i don't know why it's not working

Comment: @TiagoPina yes it's working confirmed it!, the only thing i change is the url of the image so the issue here is the path of your images. Verify if it is correct, you move one folder up and expected a folder `img`

Comment: @San sure. main folder is src: 
src --> www --> js(where is my js file)

src --> www --> img(where my images are)

src --> www(where my html files are)

Comment: in this case no need to use "../", simply use "img/green.jpg".

Comment: @San thx a lot mate, now it has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is perfectly okay. **Please note that**
Whenever you are trying to add CSS using jQuery, the CSS code added to the element on the page directly. So in this case, you should use the path considering the HTML (or View) file whenever you are trying to add any CSS based URL in your HTML using jQuery.
Above example showing the image path in your CSS file is

`background-image:url('../img/<AN IMAGE FILE>');`

which is same as the path in jQuery

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').css('background-image','url("../img/<AN IMAGE FILE>")');
```

And this is what you are dong wrong. Please correct your image path in your jQuery code considering the HTML file.

Comment: thx mate, changed the path to "img/green.jpg" and it worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Might be file hierarchy problem.

You see, when loading a style file via link tag, the relative urls will be resolved using the directory of the style file.

The same goes with html/script tags.

```
.
|   index.html
+---css
|       style.css // Just the css, you already presented above.
\---img
    blue_background.jpg
    green_background.jpg

// index.html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">Test</div>
    <script>
        function fWrong() {
            var div = document.querySelector('div[data-role="page"]');
            // "../img" does not point to the intended img directory.
            // Because index.html and img direcotry at the same level.
            div.style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/green_background.jpg')";
            setTimeout(fRight, 2000);
        }
        function fRight() {
            var div = document.querySelector('div[data-role="page"]');
            // Just one dot less. "./img" does point to the intended img directory.
            div.style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/green_background.jpg')";
        }
        setTimeout(fWrong, 2000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: solved it by changing the path to "img/green_background.jpg". thx anyway mate ;)